# ruby on rails v2 prototype issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

am going with some background information first

I have a clash between Dojo and Prototype.js on the client side, so to fix this I rewrote the client side hooks in plain javascript.

But now the issue is since Prototype.js is not being imported, the ajax functions created by the render do not work. Is there anyway I could rewrite them? Or use jquery atleast. I am using RoR v2.3.8 and updating is out of the question, so is messing with the dojo or dojo content.

I thought I could try send the prototype.js tag with the response but I have no idea how, after reading a lot of documentation am told to insert some javascript tag but where.

also is there anyway to edit actioncontroller

Comment: Normally prototype and dojo can run together without any problems. Which versions of prototype/dojo are you using? Also: you are asking a lot of questions in one question.

Comment: dojo version 2.7.2 i think and prototype version 1.6.0.3. The issue is a handler written in Dojo that I have no control over